# what's the meaning of this phrase: " top to the bottom quintile"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of this phrase: " top to the bottom quintile"
e.g. "The ratio of expected retirement income of the top to the bottom quintile was 14 in 2007"

Comment: Did you look up *quintile* in a dictionary? Do you understand the phrase *top to bottom*? Please start sentences with a capital letter. End questions with a question mark.

Comment: Related: *[“Percent” vs. “percentile”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74329)*.

Comment: @Kris - The questioner is clearly confused because the word "quintile" after "top" is implied but not present. Your recommendation would not help the questioner, and your tone is condescending and unfriendly.

Comment: @phenry The OP is expected to show background effort before posting a question on this site. Looking up a dictionary is the least one could do. Remember this is the English language site, all sentences are expected to be properly formed with capitalization, punctuation, spellings and grammar, etc. As one of us here, it is your responsibility as well to provide this information to a new member rather than take offense/ imply motives. HTH.  You can still retract your comment.

Comment: @Kris - This is a site where people ask questions to learn about the proper and customary usage of English. To expect a questioner to display a perfect command of English before asking a question is ridiculous. I certainly will not retract my comment, and your tone is still condescending and unfriendly.

Comment: There is the [ell.se] for the learners. Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: @phenry: You say this repeatedly. I wish you would more actively support ELL and the the effort to move more of these "learner" questions over there.

Answer (score 5):

The full form is

> The ratio of the top quintile to the bottom quintile.

Quintile is a 1/5 part of the whole, like percentile is a 1/100 part of the whole.

So it means (roughly paraphrased, statisticians please don't burn me!)

> In 2007, the top 20% of the population was expected to earn 14 times as much pension as the bottom 20%.